# How to hide ion-refresher using ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-v1

I'm writing an app with AngularJS 1.5.3 and Ionic 1.3.5.

I would like to hide the ion-refresher component if a certain condition is met:

```
<ion-refresher
  ng-if="data.state === 'main'"
  on-refresh="refresh()"
  spinner="lines"
  pulling-icon="ion-ios-arrow-down">
</ion-refresher>
```

Using ng-if is not working for me. I can still pull down to refresh even if the state is main.

What can I do to hide this feature?

Comment: From the official docs: _Note: Do not wrap the ion-refresher in a *ngIf. It will not render properly this way. Please use the enabled property instead to display or hide the refresher._ (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/)

Comment: Is that applicable to ionicv1?

Answer (score 1):

for ionic 4 and above, set disabled prop on the ion-refresher component

```
<ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="refreshPage($event)" disabled="true">
    <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="lines" refreshingSpinner="lines"></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
```

ref: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `enabled` attribute instead of `*ngIf` to display and hide the ion-refresher

```
<ion-refresher
  enabled = "false"
  on-refresh="refresh()"
  spinner="lines"
  pulling-icon="ion-ios-arrow-down">
</ion-refresher>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. It's still able to be pulled down.

Answer (score -1):

Use `enabled` keyword instead of `ng-if`

If the refresher is enabled or not. This should be used in place of an `ngIf`. Default is `true`.

Comment: It didn't work for me. It's still able to be pulled down.

Comment: this may help you. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/

Comment: That is for ionic 2, I am using Ionic 1. I think Ionic 1 does not support this feature.

Comment: The spinner still goes if enabled=false